# RabbitMQ cleanup after consumers

Tags: python, rabbitmq

I having problem handling the following scenario:

I have one publisher which wants to upload a lot of binary information (Like images), so instead I want it to save the image and upload a path or some reference to that file.

I have multiple **different** consumers which are reading from this MQ and do different things.
In order to do that, I simply send the information in fan-out to some exchange and define several queues for each different consumers.

This could work just fine, except for the trashing of the FS. Since no one is responsible for deleting the saved images. I need some way of defining a hook to the time **every** consumer is done consuming a message from an exchnage? Maybe setting some callback for the cleanup of the message in the exchnage?

Few notes:

1. Everything happens locally, we can assume that everything is on the same FS for simplicity.
2. I know that I can simply let the publisher save the image and give FS links for the different consumers, but this solution is problematic, since I want the publisher to be oblivious to the consumers. I don't want to update the publisher's code every time a new consumer may be used (or one can be removed).
3. I am working with python. (pika module)
4. I am new to Message Queues, so if you have a better suggestion to get things done, I would love to learn about it.

Answer (score 0):

Once the image is processed by consumer publish message `FileProcessed` with the information related to the file. That message can be picked up by another consumer which is in charge of cleaning up the messages, so that consumer will remove the file.

Additionally, make sure that your messages is re-queued in case of failure, so they will be picked up later and their processing will be retried. Make sure the retry count is limited, when the limit is reached route the message to dead letter exchange.

Some useful links below:

- [pika.BasicProperties](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/spec.html#pika.spec.BasicProperties) for handling retries.
- [RabbitMQ tutorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html)
- [Pika DLX Implementation](https://medium.com/@deepakjoseph08/re-enqueuing-with-delay-in-rabbitmq-with-pika-d30797056468)

Comment: Thanks for answering.
But the problem isn't with one consumer from one queue processing one file, it's about several consumers, consuming from the same fanout exchange. So sending `FileProcessed`  isn't enough, since I have to know everyone is done processing.
The best thing would be, If I could inject some code to run after with the last ack for that exchange.

Comment: That's very contrintuitive, since single message is single unit of work, when you have single unit of work speared across multiple messages that's something what might be revisited, for instance, you can use multiprocessing or multithreading instead of populating message to all those consumers.

Comment: The case isn't that different with multiprocessing, since I still need the last worker to know he is the last one.
What you said about a single message being a single unit of work is absolutely true. It would be more intuitive for creating multiple copies and having each one deleted. The problem is that very wasteful, and I was hoping for a way around it.

Comment: Nope, actually, you wait until all processes complete execution and than proceed with further steps, you don't have to play around with some logic of "who" and "when" completed execution: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers